# SSL error on file upload with HTTP chunked encoding

Tags: python

Trying to upload file using chunked encoding manner .

Getting the following error

```
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2423)
```

Below is the code

```
from io import BytesIO

import requests

from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

def test_upload_large_file():
    file_data = BytesIO(b'0' * (25 * 1024 * 1024))

    file = FileStorage(stream=file_data, filename='test.txt')

    headers = {'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}

    url = "<url>"

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files={'file': file})

    print(response.status_code)
    
    assert response.status_code == 200


test_upload_large_file()
```

However i change from chunked encoding to 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', it works.

Not sure why chunked encoding is throwing SSL error. I understand every HTTP 1.1 server supports chunked encoding and does not need any enabling.

I am new to python , hence might be missing something.

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer i rewrote the code to below where the content is picked up from a file but i still get the same error

```
import requests

def upload_file_chunked(url, file_path, chunk_size):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        headers = {'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=file, stream=True)

    print("Response Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)

# Example usage

url = "<url>"
file_path = "<file-path>"
chunk_size = 1024  # Specify the desired chunk size in bytes
upload_file_chunked(url, file_path, chunk_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just throw a `Transfer-Encoding` header on your request if the client isn't *using* that transfer-encoding. A chunked body has a different format than a regular one. You're confusing the server by, essentially, lying about what your request contains.

The `requests` won't generate a chunked request when using the `files` parameter to do a `multipart/form-data` upload; it can generate a chunked request if `data` is something iterable, like a filehandle (and then you don't need to add the `Transfer-Encoding` header yourself, `requests` will do it automatically) but then it needs to be the full request body, not a single "file upload" in a multipart.

In any case it's unlikely that you actually *need* to use chunked here; the size of the body isn't unknown, and 25MB is hardly large by today's standards.

Comment: thanks for reply...i rewrote the code to pick up file from a file handle...getting the same error...what confused me was the error of SSL

Comment: also 25 MB is just an example...will increase later